# Optical mouse pointer moves opposite lateral way to mouse motion

Tags: mouse

I have a Logitech wireless optical mouse and Vista 32 bit.

When I booted up the other morning I found that the mouse pointer now moves left when the mouse is moved right, and right when the mouse is moved left.  The upward and downward motions are still correct.

The day before, and for ever since installation, the mouse pointer behaved correctly. **A regular USB mouse behaves correctly**.

I have tried the following:

- disabling and then re-enabling the mouse in Device Manager
- putting in fresh batteries
- using a white instead of black mouse mat
- thoroughly cleaning the mouse rollers and ball
- disconnecting it from and reconnecting it to its receiver

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, just head to the *orientation* tab of the mouse/pointer options and reverse the **horizontal orientation** setting. Same goes for Linux distros, just find the correct dialog to change pointer settings.